# Extract value of get parameter in shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have an input that could either be `dn3321` or 
`https://domaincom/file?tag=dn3321` and I'm trying to parse the value of tag using shell.

Looks like a regex could do the trick, how would I write a one liner to detect if it's a URL if it is apply the regex to extract the value and if its not just use the value directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from the question what the full space of possible inputs looks like, but, for the simple cases you gave, you can use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

in1='dn3321'
in2='https://domaincom/file?tag=dn3321'

echo "${in1#*=}"
echo "${in2#*=}"
# prints "dn3321" twice
```

This works by removing the first `=` and any text preceding it.

Comment: you forgot the check for http ;-)

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the OP what the possible prefixes are (how should we handle `ftp://domaincom/file?tag=dn3321`? `https://domaincom/file?tag=dn3321&foo=bar`? `https://otherdomain.com/foo?bar=bat&tag=dn3321`?). So I went for the shortest example that would demonstrate the method.

Comment: thank you! I can tweak the regex now but the format of the command was my struggle, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to print out a very specific part of the string that is a url you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://domaincom/file?tag=dn3321"

if [[ "$url" =~ "${http,,}" ]] ; then
        tag=$(echo $url | cut -d'=' -f2)
fi
```

if you need something more elaborate I can post an example.